# Can't start Windows 7 after installing ubuntu 11.04

Tags: boot, windows, partitioning

When i try to start the Windows 7 loader in the ubuntu Boot Menu it says "No such partition". When i installed ubuntu, the setup detected Win7 and i chose the option to install ubuntu alongside and choose at each start. Please help!

Comment: a good place to start would be type "sudo fdisk -l" in terminal, this will write your partition table.

Comment: (write it in the terminal and edit your post!)

Answer (score 1):

From you booted Ubuntu system, use the following command in a terminal
 `sudo update-grub`
This should detect windows 7 and add it to the boot menu.